# No suitable constructor exists to convert from "const char[7]" to "TopicA"

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I have a templated SortedLinkedList class that sorts Topic A objects by the value contained in their string field.

Here's Topic A:

```
struct TopicA
{
string sValue;
double dValue;
int iValue; 

TopicA();
TopicA( const string & arg );

bool operator> ( const TopicA & rhs ) const;
bool operator< ( const TopicA & rhs ) const;
bool operator== ( const TopicA & rhs ) const;
bool operator!= ( const TopicA & rhs ) const;
};
```

I want to find the position in the list where a TopicA object with `"tulgey"` in its string field would be stored, so I call `AList.getPosition( "tulgey" );` Here is the `getPosition()` header:

```
template <class ItemType>
int SortedLinkedList<ItemType>::getPosition( const ItemType& anEntry ) const
```

But when I try to call `getPosition()` the compiler gives me the error in the title. Why? Don't I have a conversion constructor from `string` to `TopicA`?

If it makes any difference here's the definition of `TopicA( const string & arg )`:

```
TopicA::TopicA( const string & arg ) : sValue( arg ), dValue( 0 ), iValue( 0 )
{
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably invoking two implicit conversions, from `const char[7]` to `std::string`, and from `std::string` to `TopicA`. But you are only allowed one implicit conversion. You can fix the problem by being more explicit:

```
AList.getPosition( std::string("tulgey") ); // 1 conversion
AList.getPosition( TopicA("tulgey") );      // 1 conversion
```

Alternatively, you can give `TopicA` a constructor taking a `const char*`:

```
TopicA( const char * arg ) : sValue( arg ), dValue( 0 ), iValue( 0 ) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

These would work

```
AList.getPosition( TopicA("tulgey") ); 

AList.getPosition( TopicA("tulgey") ); 

std::string query = "tulgey";
AList.getPosition( query  );
```

Alternatively you can define another conversion constructor

```
TopicA( const char* arg );
```

Now things will work as you want

```
AList.getPosition( "tulgey" );
```

The problem is that **you needed 2 implicit conversions**, the **standard allows only 1**. Remember that **string literals are represented as `char` arrays** in `C++` and not `string`.

1. `char*`/`char[]` -> `std::string`
2. `std::string` -> `TopicA`